# cordova iframe with html inside not showing on iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I am trying to show an iframe inside my ionic app, but somehow, it appears on the browser, but it doesn't appear on the iOS device. I want to fill it with html code. 
My code:

```
<ion-content>
    <iframe width="300px" height="325px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" ng-attr-srcdoc="{{model.html}}">
    </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe is not supported by IOS via Cordova before 6.4 correctly.

the statement by cordova was that ios does not support iframes.

if you want to need something like iframe before 6.4 you have to build it by yourself i.e. as a textarea or a embedded section with scrolling.

if you are using 6.4 or newer, look at the following responses.

Comment: I see, can you give me a hint wich is the best techique to display a web page with cordova, if not with iframe. My web page starts with something like: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "---">
<html><head>
  <meta name="description" content="---">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Mozilla/4.72 [en] (WinNT; U) [Netscape]">
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800;URL=---">
<title>---</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function validate() {  ...and so on

Comment: i think a external web page should be marked as external, normaly you dont need more than a link to it. if you want to open it without the app is forcing to the background complete have a look cordova inappbrowser

Comment: This answer is incorrect on two levels. Firstly, iOS supports iframes just fine. The issue is Cordova-specific and related to the use of the srcdoc attribute. See my answer for the real solution.

Comment: yes, its fixed in cordova 6.4, but i have to work with 5.x because of old android phones that can't be updated. there it does not work. at the moment i wrote the answer it doesn't work. and official statement of cordova "was" that ios does not support iframes.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that, by default, Cordova doesn't support srcdoc. The solution for recent versions of Cordova is simple. Edit config.xml for the project and add:

```
<allow-navigation href="about:*" />
```

I have tested this on Cordova 6.4.0 and it fixes the issue: it allows Cordova apps with iframes to use srcdoc.

*(The accepted answer is incorrect. iOS supports iframes just fine. marshall119us's answer was ok for previous versions of Cordova, but is obsolete.)*

Comment: did you test it on android devices? i had problems with it

Comment: I'm afraid I have only tested this for iOS. I will be dealing with Android soon, so let us know if you figure out the correct solution there! :)

Comment: @mtizziani Finally I can report that this works on Android as well.

Comment: @logidelic Thank you for this! It helped me a lot :-) Now, I can finally use srcdoc iframes in Cordova iOS

Answer (score 1):

Default Cordova behavior prevents iframes that use srcdoc from displaying content. To override this, special case it in your MainViewController.m by adding this code (valid as of Cordova v6.2.0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL* url = [request URL];

    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"about"]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
          return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    }
}
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7379

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13982181)

Comment: @Liam Updated answer to include relevant code - thanks for the advice! Note that the accepted answer is incorrect since iOS does support iFrames.

Comment: Any chance the downvoter could leave a comment on their reasoning? Would love to restore the rep points now that the answer is fully fleshed out. :)

Comment: @Liam - I'm a newbie to posting answers and curious about 1) why answer was recommended for deletion, and 2) whether downvote can be reversed since answer was updated with requested info. Help appreciated.

Comment: It was recommended for deletion (not by me) because your answer was a link only. The downvote can be revresed but only by the person who downvoted it. This is anoymous and I didn't do it. So your likely too late. To avoid downvotes, etc. read all the [help] and follow the guidence in it.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was that i recently retested my phone to factory reset. I had to update my apps my apps.